# Select columns from dataframe on condition they exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns (columns names are numbers; 1, 2, ...) and I want to copy some of them if they do exist.

For example `df1 = df[[1,2,3,4]]`
But it might happen that some columns do not exist in df, eg df might only have columns 1, 2, and 4 or columns 1, and 2 etc

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter, this will handle non-existent columns:

```
In [97]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,4])
df.loc[:,df.columns.isin([1,2,3,4,])]

Out[97]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 4]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 39):

It is simpler to directly calculate the set of common columns and ask for them:

```
df[df.columns & [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

(The `&` operator is the (set) intersection operator.)

Comment: I prefer this solution over the original accepted one, as this is simpler to be implemented in one line

Comment: I get a `FutureWarning` stating that this method is deprecated as of 1.2.4, and that `index.intersection(other)` should be used instead.

Comment: Indeed this doesn't work anymore. ```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (35,) (69,) ```

Answer (score 4):

One possible way:

```
df[df.columns.intersection(set(['list', 'of', 'cols']))]
```

For example:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3,4])
df
Out[1]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Index: []

In [2]:
df[df.columns.intersection(set([1, 2, 2, 5]))]
Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2]
Index: []

In [3]:
pd.__version__
Out[3]:
'1.2.1'
```

Comment: This is the modern, non-deprecated way.